# How to write this in a simpler less ridiculous way

Tags: javascript, jquery

This just seems absurd to me. Should I use array instead or is there some other better solution?

```
$('.hoursRange').change(function() {
    if ('0' == $(this).val())
    {
        $(this).val('00');
        return false;
    }
    if ('1' == $(this).val())
    {
        $(this).val('01');
        return false;
    }
    if ('2' == $(this).val())
    {
        $(this).val('02');
        return false;
    }
    if ('3' == $(this).val())
    {
        $(this).val('03');
        return false;
    }
    if ('4' == $(this).val())
    {
        $(this).val('04');
        return false;
    }
    if ('5' == $(this).val())
    {
        $(this).val('05');
        return false;
    }
    if ('6' == $(this).val())
    {
        $(this).val('06');
        return false;
    }
    if ('7' == $(this).val())
    {
        $(this).val('07');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: this is seems complicated of course. Why aren't the dropdown values already prependended ?

Comment: Hmm, I +1'd you but it cannot be a dropdown since how can you set the value of the dropdown to 06 if the value is 6? Or can jQuery change the actual value="6" to value="06" using .val()?

Comment: @mplungjan Input values are strings. So it's not 06 but '06' what $(this).val() returns.

Comment: So please re-read my comment and imagine quotes around my numbers. The question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).val('0' + $(this).val());`?

Comment: please add a check to see that $(this).val() is 0 to 7 to begin with

Comment: But you accepted a sub-optimal suggestion unless jQuery automatically casts the .val() into an int or float due to the + which normally converts to string when concatenating to a string before it.

Comment: seems like wrong solution has been accepted as correct answer. please check out the rest of responses.

Answer (score 5):

```
if($(this).val().length == 1) {
    $(this).val('0' + $(this).val());
}
```

Or just pad all of the single digits with zeros on page load, rather than onchange:

```
$('.hoursRange option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().length == 1;
}).each(function() { 
    $(this).val('0' + $(this).val());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WKdWq/

Answer (score 5):

Just use a regex:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^[0-7]$/, "0$&"));
```

Comment: this seems to be the most appropriate answer that I agree with without further info from the author

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = $(this).val();
if ($(this).val().length < 2) {
   $(this).val('0' + value);
}
```

Comment: would a trim be handy here or are we sure that the string of the .val() is the length of the digit it contains?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.hoursRange').change(function() {
   if (parseInt($(this).val(),10)<10) $(this).val("0"+parseInt($(this).val(),10));
}
```

Comment: the second parseInt is useless as when you are appending to it a string you are converting it to a string again...

Comment: Not if the value had leading 0s

Comment: And we need the 10 in the parseInt(,10) since 08 and 09 are invalid octals (not that the author wanted 8 or 9 in the question)

Answer (score 1):

A function for zero-padding is available from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript). Using that, you can simply do:

```
$('.hoursRange').change(function() {
    $(this).val( zerofill($(this).val(), 2) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on jQuery but it is awkward.
I would check boundary condition `(0<=$(this).val()<=7)` and if not met return `false`.  Otherwise

```
var v = $(this).val();
v='0'+v;
$(this).val(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hoursRange').change(function() {
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/(\b\d\b)/,'0$1') );
}
```

I don't see you needing any conditional statements or additional expensive jQuery calls in here.